# Como fazer uma relação ternária em Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Qual é a melhor maneira de fazer uma relação ternária em Laravel?

Estou a fazer uma aplicação "multi cliente/empresa" (tipo basecamp) e apareceu a seguinte relação:

- um `user` tem uma `(0 .. n) permissão` naquela organização, sendo que utilizadores, permissões e organizações são entidades.

Basicamente no BD teria de ter uma tabela com as chaves:

```
user_id
permission_id
organization_id
```

Agora o problema é saber como faço isso no Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

Em Laravel, os relacionamentos são tratados de uma forma muito prática, através das funções hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo, BelongsToMany, hasManyThrough, morphMany, morphToMany e morphedByMany.

Digamos que esta tabela que irá armazenar as chaves primárias das três tabelas se chame links(apenas um exemplo) e que tenhamos as models Users, Permissions, Organizations e Links.

Quando se um uma relação n para n(many to many) é necessário que se tenha uma tabela intermediária, que no caso é a links. Laravel(Eloquent ORM) possui algumas facilidades para interagir com essa tabela.

Se a localização de suas models está no padrão: app/models

Então em sua model users iremos criar o relacionamento:

```
public function permissions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Permissions', 'Links');
}

public function organization()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Organizations', 'Links');
}
```

Na controller poderemos fazer o seguinte:

```
$permissions = User::find($id)->with('permissions')->get();
```

ou

```
$permissions = User::find($id)->permissions;
```

Isso irá recuperar todas as permissoões de um usuário dentre todas as organizações, então tem que limitar a seleção para uma organização em específico.

```
$permissions = User::find($id)->with('permissions', 'organization')->where('links.organization_id', '=', $organization_id)->get();
```

ou

```
$permissions = User::find($id)->with('permissions')->whereHas('organization',function($query) use ($organization_id) 
{
  $query->whereId($organization_id);
})->get();
```

Crie também os relacionamentos restantes das outras models.

Obs: Não tenho muito experiência nesses relacionamentos mais complexos, mas isso é o que entendi desde o período que conheci laravel.

Documentação do laravel:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Answer (score 2):

Não respondendo diretamente sua pergunta, mas complementando...

Na verdade, um usuário pode ter multiplas permissoes e uma permissão pode ser utilizada por multiplos usuarios, só aí você já tem uma relação ternária.

O mesmo vale para a relação entre permissões e entidade, pois você precisará de uma tabela intermediária que representa a relação muitos-para-muitos.

O que provavelmente você precisa nesse caso é focar em uma arquitetura *multi-tenant* (multi-inquilino) pois a sua pergunta está mais relacionada a arquitetura do que a relação de entidades em Laravel.

Comment: Sua pergunta não soluciona o problema da pergunta.